# UIActivityViewController inside iMessage app/extension

Tags: ios, imessage, imessage-extension

I am trying to show UIActivityViewController inside iMessage app. In both modes (compact/expanded) it is not shown properly/fully. See attached images. Is there any way to correct this?

[image: Expanded mode]
[image: Compact mode]

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? On iPad, the vc can hide beneath the top bar. And the interface for chosen activities can be blocked from view just as the UIActivityViewController is in your images, so it seems pretty pervasive.

Comment: Nope, I didn't find any solution to this issue :S.

Comment: This also happens when you select "Create Event" if using data detection through a UITextView in a Messages app. I've cross-posted it to Apple Developer Forum and made a bug report (thus far unanswered). Gonna keep looking for solution...

Comment: Learned a few things, but not enough to yet provide an answer. My primary view controller is a UITableViewController. It presents accurately. When I changed the UI and made the view controller a subclass of UIViewController (no longer UITableViewController), no matter what changes I made to frame/bounds/content, there was an extra chunk of space at top and bottom that coincidentally seemed to match the two bars (86 for the top, iir, including 20 for status bar). I was going to just live with it, but then made another UI change. [...comment too long for one comment...]

Comment: ...I used the UITableViewController as the main vc, and then created interface to add my UIViewController subclass as another child view of the Messages view controller. Miraculously, my UIViewController subclass displayed perfectly with regard to the Messages bars! So I then created a blank vc as the first child vc, and suddenly the UITableViewController hid content behind the Messages bars. Conclusion...there are adjustments made to the first child view controller and/or table view controllers that are beyond our control, but there may be possibilities if using UIViewController subclass.